# several forms on the same page with django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

i have a very simple model... something like this:

```
class MachineTransTable(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.ForeignKey('File', related_name='the_file')
    source = models.TextField()
    target = models.TextField()
    ...
```

What I'd like to do is to have a page where the user has the source on the left (disable), the target on the right (editable) and a submit button to post the edited target text for EACH selected object in the MachineTransTable table. Here are some more information to better understand my request:

- A page refers to a single file and there are several (sometimes hundreds) of objects in the MachineTransTable table belonging to the same file
- Each time the user edit a single target and hit the submit button for that object, the object is saved/updated (depending on the initial value of the object) in the DB and the the user can continue to edit all the other objects...
- At the end of the page there is another submit button which is used to exit from the page at the end of the work (all the objects have been edited/updated). If an object has not been edited/updated, it keeps its original value.

I tried to use a formset but I guess it's not the right choice... This is the file forms.py

```
class SegmentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SegmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.id:
            self.fields['source'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = MachineTransTable
        fields = ['source','target',]

SegmentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(File, MachineTransTable, form=SegmentForm, fields=('source','target'), extra=0)
```

and the view.py file is:

```
class CatUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):

    Model = MachineTransTable
    context_object_name = 'file'
    template_name = 'app_cat/cat.html'
    form_class = SegmentForm
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        formset = SegmentFormSet(instance=self.get_object())
        context['formset_Segment'] = formset
        return context
```

Using this approach, I have a single form and all the related objects are saved/updated at once when the submit button is hit...

What can I do to achieve what I described above? Thanks

Comment: So you got two kinds of submit button, one for a single field, the other for the page. Now you want to make this buttons work?

Comment: The problem is not make a buttons... the problem is how to have several (hundreds eventually) forms... each one with its submit button.... I tried to figure out how to do it with django but for the moment I don't have a clue... and the page button is not really a problem... I guess with some coding I can do it with jquery but that's not what I want to do... I prefer to have a server side solution with django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your choice is correct, you should not use  **several (hundreds eventually) forms** here if the field in the same model. For two reasons:

- You have to do a lot of repeat job to write so many forms and that is easy to make mistake and hard to maintain.
- You still have to connect the database and update the record no matter how many field had been edit, and they almost efficiency.

But if you really want to do this,you can just use Ajax to post the current parameters name to the api, then update it, For instance, you have a button for target field:

```
<a href="api/table_id" class="button target">value_in_the_html</a>
```

Use Ajax to post the field name and value:

```
$ajax({
    url: "api/table_id",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {"field": "target", "value": "value_in_the_html"}
});
```

In view.py:

```
def UpdateTable(request, id):
    field = request.POST.get("field", None)
    value = request.POST.get("value", None)
    machine = MachineTransTable.objects.filter(id=id).first()
    machine.getattr(machine,field) = value
    machine.save()
    return HttpResponse("Saved!")
```

Comment: Thanks Aison, I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for... let me try to be really low level... What I'm looking for is the correct way to have a single form in form.py which take care of the object edit/update, a CBV which provide all the different forms (each one with its unique ID) as a list in the context and a template where I loop on that list. In that way I can have several forms in my page but no repetition and DRY is respected... Of course I can use then your suggestion (the ajax part) for updating the target field

Comment: OK. After few test I realize that using several forms in the same page means that each time I update a form, I need to reload the full page... which is not an efficient approach... much better to work on the client side with jquery and post to the server each update when needed... no page reload and much better user experience